# How do I create an observable which emits a value from an ngrx selector, then another value after a delay?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

Given an ngrx selector:

```
store.select('count')
```

I want to create an observable that will emit values emitted by the selector, then emit another specific value after a delay.

Using `concat` doesn't work as (I assume) the selector doesn't complete, so the 0 is never emitted:

```
this.count$ = concat(store.select('count'), of(0).pipe(delay(2000)));
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-selector-delay?file=src/app/my-counter/my-counter.component.ts
- click 'Increment' button - Current Count should change to 1 then back to 0 after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to emit the `store.select('count')` value, then essentially reset it to `0` after not receiving an emission for 2 seconds, you can use a [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) to create a source that emits two values:

1. The emitted `count`
2. The "default" value of `0` after 2000ms

The trick here is that the second value (`0`) will NOT be emitted if another `store.select('count')` value is received, because `switchMap` will create a new source and "switch" to that:

```js
this.count$ = store.select('count').pipe(
  switchMap(count => concat(
    of(count),
    of(0).pipe(delay(2000))
  ))
);
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67134933?file=src/app/my-counter/my-counter.component.ts) demo.

---

It might even be worth creating a custom operator:

```js
  this.count$ = this.store.select('count').pipe(
    resetAfterDelay(0, 2000)
  );
```

```js
export function resetAfterDelay<T>(defaultValue: T, delayMs: number) {
  return switchMap((value: T) => concat(
    of(value),
    of(defaultValue).pipe(delay(delayMs))
  ));
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67134933-custom-operator?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-counter%2Fmy-counter.component.ts)

Comment: I would like a solution of this simplicity but I can't get either of these to work reliably, and they never seem to work after the first emission. See my-counter.component.ts in modified examples here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-selector-delay-merge and https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-selector-delay-takeuntil-interval

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "work reliably"?  I've added console logging to your SB samples and they both seem to work perfectly: [Delay/Merge](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-selector-delay-merge-6yuvlz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-counter%2Fmy-counter.component.ts) | [TakeUntil/Interval](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-selector-delay-takeuntil-interval-u6pq3c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-counter%2Fmy-counter.component.ts)

Comment: Oh, I see your solution and what you really wanted.  You wanted the `0` to be emitted 2 seconds after EVERY emissions of `store.select('count')`.  I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an approach using `combineLatest` and `BehaviorSubject`

We are hold a value in a subject and create a timer that emits value 0 after 2s. So we have two Observables, one emits immediately and the other after 2s. We combine this two and the effect is a single observable as desired

```
  valueHolderSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);

  ...

    this.count$ = combineLatest([
      store.select("count").pipe(
        tap(x => this.valueHolderSubject$.next(x)),
        tap(() =>
          timer(2000).subscribe({
            next: () => {
              this.valueHolderSubject$.next(0);
            }
          })
        ),
        map(() => this.valueHolderSubject$.value),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      ),
      this.valueHolderSubject$
    ]).pipe(map(([, x]) => x));
```

[Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-selector-delay-f3w7pb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-counter%2Fmy-counter.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for this, while it worked I went for a simpler solution as in my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

A per my comments on the answer from BizzyBob, I was getting unreliable results. But I refined it to work using:

```
this.count$ = merge(
      store.select('count'), 
      store.select('count').pipe(delay(2000), map(_ => 0))
);
```

See stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-selector-delay-merge-working?file=src/app/my-counter/my-counter.component.ts

Comment: One potential problem with this solution is that you will ALWAYS emit `0` 2000ms after  EVERY emission.  If multiple `count` values are emitted in less that 2 seconds, your `0` value will clear out a newly received value in less than 2 seconds.  See my updated answer for a solution that prevents this.

Comment: Yep, good catch I had not thought that deeply about the behaviour in that situation.